# How to send a request from Postman going to a Function in ASP.Net MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-services, asp.net-web-api

I'm having a problem trying to send a request from Postman going to the Class function.

Here is my code:

```
 public ChargeInitResponse Post([FromBody]LocaliseChargeInit value)
        {
            if (value == null)
            {
                throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }

            ChargeInitResponse reply = new PaymentIntegrationService
            {
                ChargeInitRequest = value
            }.PushChargeInit();

            if (reply == null)
            {
                throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);
            }
            return reply;
        }
```

ChargeInitResponse Class

```
public class ChargeInitResponse
    {
        public string partnerTxID { get; set; }
        public string request { get; set; }
        public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }
    }
```

LocaliseChargeInit Class

```
public class LocaliseChargeInit : ChargeInit
    {
        public string CodeVerifier { get; set; }
        public ServiceRequestHeader Header { get; set; }
    }
```

ServiceRequestHeader Class

```
 public class ServiceRequestHeader
    {
        public string Authorization { get; set; }
        public string Date { get; set; }
    }
```

So now my problem is I don't know how to throw a request to the `ChargeInitResponse Post` via Postman. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: I recommend you look at Postman documentation https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/api_documentation/intro_to_api_documentation/

Comment: @ikey what do mean by  "how to post in a class function"?

Comment: I'm sorry for the question I've just edited my question to make it less more confusing. I've already resolved my issue using @Bosco comment. Thank you.